# malware text show up intermittently in my joomla site content

Tags: joomla, malware

My joomla site infected with some malware but i dont know how to rid with this..its appearing sometimes in site but its still showing in google cache of site. below is the link of google cache website :
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:V5KCr9zRmCkJ:www.highwaysafetygroup.com/index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D64%26Itemid%3D70+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a

Below is actual site link : www.highwaysafetygroup.com

can any help me out?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is add &tmpl=component to the URL has has the problem. If the problem goes away, then the problem is in a module somewhere. If not, then switch templates. If the problem goes away, check your template files. Next turn off javascript in your browser and see if the problem persists. If it goes away, then the problem is javascript inserted in to your database.

Comment: Thanks for guide but its not showing all time in pages. Its showing intermediately. So how can i debug this issue. :(

Comment: If it is showing up intermittently, then you will have to do the same process repeatedly until you get the problem to happen. There is no easy way or short cut other than narrowing down the possibilities so you don't have to go through the whole site to fix it.

Comment: thanks brent, i have written google cache link of the site. Can you look at that link ? i think might be you will get idea for that malware. because actual malware showing only there.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure since you can't manipulate anything, but it looks like the spam is being injected immediately before the component content is displayed, not within the content itself, which would lead me to believe that the code is either in your template or other related file. If it was in the DB it would likely be within the component area.